# How to sort in descending order with numpy?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
A = array([[1, 3, 2, 7],
           [2, 4, 1, 3],
           [6, 1, 2, 3]])
```

I would like to sort the rows of this matrix in descending order and get the arguments of the sorted matrix like this:

```
As = array([[3, 1, 2, 0],
            [1, 3, 0, 2],
            [0, 3, 2, 1]])
```

I did the following:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[1, 3, 2, 7], [2, 4, 1, 3], [6, 1, 2, 3]])
As = numpy.argsort(A, axis=1)
```

But this gives me the sorting in ascending order. Also, after I spent some time looking for a solution in the internet, I expect that there must be an argument to `argsort` function from numpy that would reverse the order of sorting. But, apparently **there is no such argument! Why!?**

There is an argument called `order`. I tried, by guessing, `numpy.argsort(..., order=reverse)` but it does not work.

I looked for a solution in previous questions here and I found that I can do:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[1, 3, 2, 7], [2, 4, 1, 3], [6, 1, 2, 3]])
As = numpy.argsort(A, axis=1)
As = As[::-1]
```

For some reason, `As = As[::-1]` does not give me the desired output.

Well, I guess it must be simple but I am missing something.

How can I sort a numpy array in descending order?

Comment: You need to use `np.argsort(A, axis=1)[:, ::-1]`. Using just `[::-1]` reverses axis 0: you want to reverse axis 1.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that `As` is not the sorted version of `A` in your top example but the sorted version of a different matrix?

Comment: It is the argument of the sorted version of `A`. @Swier

Comment: Or two *hackish* ways : `np.argsort(-A, axis=1)` and `A.shape[1] -1 - np.argsort(A, axis=1)`.

Comment: There's no `reverse` option in NumPy's `sort` or `argsort` functions because reversing an array is so efficient (it just changes the strides, no data need be copied). A solution via sorting `-A` would work, but that creates two new arrays instead of one. For large arrays this is not great.

Comment: The function documentation explains the `order` parameter.  It isn't what you thought.

Comment: Yes, first I tried without reading the documentation, then I ind that it is not what I need.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just multiply your matrix by -1 to reverse order:

```
[In]: A = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 7],
                    [2, 4, 1, 3],
                    [6, 1, 2, 3]])
[In]: print( np.argsort(-A) )
[Out]: [[3 1 2 0]
        [1 3 0 2]
        [0 3 2 1]]
```